# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index' probleme pour recuperer des donnees

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, _LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#cfe3e]], state: _HomePageState#0cc63):
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  HomePage HomePage:file:///C:/Users/NadjiBiSenegal20/app_pompe/lib/loginPage.dart:299:56
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      _HomePageState.build (package:app_pompe/HomePage.dart:283:79)
#1      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4870:27)
#2      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4754:15)
#3      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4928:11)
#4      Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4477:5)

Navigator.push(
                                      context,
                                      MaterialPageRoute(
                                          builder: (context) =>
                                              HomePage.fromBase64(
                                                  resp['accessToken'],infosUser, infosLanguage)));

 Container(
                                        child: Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                              top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
                                          child: SizedBox(
                                            child: Text(
                                                "${widget.infosUser['address']['address']}, ${widget.infosUser['address']['city']['name']}, ${widget.infosUser['address']['city']['region']['name']},",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    color:
                                                    GlobalVariable.appColor,
                                                    fontSize: _size / 80,
                                                    fontWeight:
                                                    FontWeight.bold),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.right),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
```

Comment: Vous devez ajouter des détails pertinents à votre question lorsque vous postez, quelles ont été vos tentatives pour résoudre le problème, etc. Je ne sais pas si l'anglais est la langue officielle de SO, mais vous aurez certainement plus d'yeux sur votre question s'il est affiché en anglais.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because you does not provide all information to investigate this, but i guess problem is with this line:

```
fontSize: _size / 80,
```

Are you sure that `_size` is a number ? If not, use this:

```
fontSize: _size.toInt() / 80,
```